# unable to find the latest jar of ksoap2

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

Where can I find the latest **ksoap2 jar** ?

https://code.google.com/archive/p/ksoap2-android/downloads -

The latest I see here is from 2010 (2.4).

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/k/Downloadksoap2android252jar.htm

Comment: that's 2.5,, as far as I know there is already 3.5 version.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ksoap2-android project provides a lightweight and efficient SOAP
>   client library for the Android platform.
>
> It is a fork of the kSOAP2 library that is tested mostly on the
>   Android platform, but should also work on other platforms using Java
>   libraries.

You can use stable **[ksoap2-android-2.5.2.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/k/Downloadksoap2android252jar.htm)**